# Get childnode by type or class instead of index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child

I'm trying to get a specific child node from the DOM using JS or jQuery.
I figured how to obtain a NodeList containing that node, but the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp) only specifies that one can access the nodes by index. This seems risky, as I have no guarantee of their order.

```
$(".axis")[0].childNodes()
```

returns the following `NodeList [...]`

```
​
0: <g class="tick" style="opacity: 1;" transform="translate(0,319.94835680751174)">
​
1: <g class="tick" style="opacity: 1;" transform="translate(0,237.31924882629104)">
​
2: <path class="domain" d="M0,1H0V353H0" style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(34, 34, 34); shape-rendering: crispedges;">
​
3: <text>
​
length: 4
```

I doubt that looping through each node and checking its `HTML` for class or type is the best way. I tried `$(".axis")[0].childNodes.getElementsByClass("domain")` but this returns `TypeError: $(...)[0].childNodes.getElementsByClass is not a function.`

Is their a more direct way to access them by type or class instead?

Comment: With jQuery, if you want to search for child with that contains a tag named `path` with `domain` class, you can use `$(".axis path.domain")`. Space in the selector means descending (child) search.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about that, but I also need to know to which parent it belongs. Whith this approach I only have the children nodes, but don't know to which parent they belong. Would it be any easier to retrieve the parent from the child, than the opposite (as I try in my original post)?

Comment: You can use `.parent()` on the child (to retrieve the immediate parent), or `.closest(".axis")` to search ancestors and return the first one with the `.axis` class.

Comment: Or, you can select the parent with `var parent = $(".axis")`, and search for children using `var children = parent.find("path.domain")`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `$(".axis")[0].find("domain")` returns an error `TypeError: $(...)[0].find is not a function`. It only works on the parent  `$(".axis").find("path")`. The difference is that  `$(".axis")[0]` is a  single `<g>` element, whereas `$(".axis")` is an object of `<g>` elements. Why can't I simply use `.find()` on the single `<g>`?

Comment: `document.querySelector(".axis .domain")` - will find the first element with the classname "axis" then, within that element will find the first child element with the classname "domain". Is that what you are after?

Comment: @sc28, when you select a children with index, like this - `$(".axis")[0]` -, you're, in fact, selecting a native child node that does not contains `.find` method (this is a jQuery function). To select a specific jQuery object (by index), you can use `.eq`. Like this: `$(".axis").eq(0)`.

Comment: @mrlew aha, ok thanks for the clarification. in the meantime I also tried your bottom-up approach using ancestor and this works: i can start from the child node with  `$(".axis path.domain")[0]`, then find  its direct parent axis with `$(".axis path.domain")[0].closest(".axis")`. Thank you and others for the clarifications! If you wish to post the `.closest(".axis")` approach, I'll accept it as best answer.

Comment: @RandyCasburn thanks but not quite: i particularly needed to establish the link between the parent and child, not just retrieve the child. @mrlew 's solution using `.closest()` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods in jQuery the [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and [children()](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method.

They both return elements that match a descendant selector of the parent node however `children()` will only search the first level of descendant children whereas `find()` will iterate through all children - obviously `children()` is the preferred method for a faster execution time.

An example

```
$('#parent').find('.foo').addClass('bar');
```

would add the class `bar` to every single element within the `#parent` element that has the class name `foo`

whereas

```
$('#parent').children('.foo').addClass('bar');
```

would only return the outermost `.foo` element from this DOM structure:

```
<div id="parent">
  <p class="foo"></p>
  <div>
    <p class="foo"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `.find()`, I indeed overlooked that option. However, as commented in my original question, I cannot use `$(".axis")[0].find("domain")`  on a single `<g>`, why might that be?

Comment: you are missing the class identifier `.` there - isnt .domain a `path` element in your answer also

Comment: Right, sorry for the typo, i originally tried searching for the type "path" instead of class "domain". Either way, with or without `.` the error `TypeError: $(...)[0].find is not a function` occurs, even if jQuery is present.

Comment: Oh...that's because you are accessing the node by using the array. Not a jQuery object. Assign that key to a var then pass the var to the jQuery function $(var).find()

Comment: Your code does not work. You are missing a couple of single or double quotes.